# C++ Iterating through vector of structs

Tags: c++, vector, console

Issues with looping through vector of struct.

I am currently working on a console snake game in C++.

I store the grid information in a vector of a struct.

```
struct item
{
    int xCoord;
    int yCoord;
    int colour;
};
```

```
vector<item> gridInfo;
```

Then I loop through the coordinates of the grid to see if there should be something printed.

```
    for(int y = 0; y < 10; y++)
    {
        for(int x = 0; x < 10; x++)
        {
            for(auto it = px.begin(); it != px.end(); ++it)
            {
                if((*it).xCoord == x && (*it).yCoord == y)
                {
                    SetConsoleTextAttribute(console_color, (*it).colour);
                }
                else
                {
                    SetConsoleTextAttribute(console_color, 255);
                }
            }
            cout << ("  ");
        }
        cout << "\n";
    }
```

I've managed to get the main block of the snake (head) working with movement.

However as soon I add the "food" to the vector, it starts colouring the food only.

```
    if(px.back().colour != 207)
    {
        px.push_back({rand() % 10, rand() % 10, 207});
    }
```

For those wondering why I have px instead of grindInfo, because the display runs in a function which is called from main.

```
int main()
{
    int localDirection = -1;
    vector<item> gridInfo;

    srand(time(0));

    gridInfo.push_back({4, 4, 191});

    while(true)
    {
        localDirection = kbInput(localDirection);
        gridInfo = gameLogic(gridInfo, localDirection);
        Sleep(1000);
    }
}
```

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: *I add the "food" to the vector, it starts colouring the food only* What food?

Comment: please read about [mcve] and try to provide one

Comment: The apples the snake eats @kiner_shah

Comment: OT: don't write `(*foo).bar` but rather `foo->bar`. It's the same thing, but latter is the usual way it's done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After pushing the food information, the first element of the vector is the head information and the second one is the food information.

In the loop `if((*it).xCoord == x && (*it).yCoord == y)` where `(x, y)` is the coordinate of the head, the color is first set to `(*it).colour` and then set to `255`, assuming the coordinate of the food differs from one of the head.

You should check if matching coordinate is found and set the color to `255` only if no matches are found.

```cpp
    for(int y = 0; y < 10; y++)
    {
        for(int x = 0; x < 10; x++)
        {
            bool found = false;
            for(auto it = px.begin(); it != px.end(); ++it)
            {
                if((*it).xCoord == x && (*it).yCoord == y)
                {
                    SetConsoleTextAttribute(console_color, (*it).colour);
                    found = true;
                    // uncomment if you want to give priority to the first match
                    //break;
                }
            }
            if(!found)
            {
                SetConsoleTextAttribute(console_color, 255);
            }
            cout << ("  ");
        }
        cout << "\n";
    }
```

Another way is setting the color to `255` first and then performing the loop.

```cpp
    for(int y = 0; y < 10; y++)
    {
        for(int x = 0; x < 10; x++)
        {
            SetConsoleTextAttribute(console_color, 255);
            for(auto it = px.begin(); it != px.end(); ++it)
            {
                if((*it).xCoord == x && (*it).yCoord == y)
                {
                    SetConsoleTextAttribute(console_color, (*it).colour);
                    found = true;
                    // uncomment if you want to give priority to the first match
                    //break;
                }
            }
            cout << ("  ");
        }
        cout << "\n";
    }
```

Comment: Why does my else not work? Thanks your solution works.

Comment: @proace Because the `else` part sets the color to `255` whenever the coordinate doesn't match, even after finding matching element.